# What does P2W mean?

Tags: terminology

What does P2W mean?  I've heard it used in reference to various free to play games.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It means "pay to win".

Generally, it's used to describe games that have a cash store where game items can be bought with real money, and those items are perceived as too big of an advantage.

In essence, if you don't spend additional money, others who have done so will have the upper hand.